# store the query result of dividing two columns in another table

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I have a database taxidata which contains two tables taxidata and taxifare. Now I want to divide two columns from the two tables respectively and then store the result in another table but I am unable to do that.

```
select (taxifare.fare_amount/taxidata.trip_distance) into fare_mile(fare_per_mile) from taxifare inner join taxidata on taxifare.id = taxidata.id;
```

Comment: use `insert into fare_mile (<some taxi id>, fare_per_mile) select (taxifare.....) from taxi....`